# Overloading operator=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This may be a trivial question, however I didn't find a satisfactory answer and cannot really figure out what's going on.

Suppose you have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    void operator=(int)
    {
        std::cout << "calling Foo::operator=(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo a, b;
    a = 10; // it works, of course, no questions here
    a = b; // why does this work?
}
```

Since I overloaded `operator=` in `Foo`, I would expect the line `a = b` inside `main()` to spit a compiler error (that is, `a.operator=(b)` should not compile, as there is no implicit conversion from `b` to `int`, the latter being the input type of `Foo::operator=(int)`). Why does the assignment `a = b` silently works, and what exactly is going on? Is the compiler generating a "default" `operator=(const Foo&)` even in the case when I overloaded it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is generating a default, trivial `Foo& operator=(const Foo&)`. There only four cases in which the implicit copy assignment operator will NOT be generated:

- you explicitly told it not to (e.g. `Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete`)
- you declared one yourself taking a `Foo` (or `Foo&` or `const Foo&`)
- your class has a non-trivially-assignable member (e.g. a `unique_ptr<T>`)
- your class has a defined move assignment operator or constructor (thanks Brian)

**Update** Here's some relevant parts from the standard.

12.8.18:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If
>   the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy
>   assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted

Ok, but you *did* declare a copy assignment operator, right? Or did you? What exactly *is* a copy assignment operator:

12.8.17:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of
>   class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.
>   121 [ Note:
>   An overloaded assignment operator must be declared to have only one parameter; see 13.5.3. — end note ]
>   [ Note: More than one form of copy assignment operator may be declared for a class. — end note ] [ Note:
>   If a class `X` only has a copy assignment operator with a parameter of type `X&`, an expression of type `const X`
>   cannot be assigned to an object of type `X`

So no. The function you declared as `Foo::operator=(int)`, while being an assignment operator, is not a *copy* assignment operator. Hence it doesn't satisfy the condition in the previous paragraph for not implicitly declaring one.

All the other conditions are defined in 12.8.23:

> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X is defined as deleted if X has:

- a variant member with a non-trivial corresponding assignment operator and X is a union-like class, or
- a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof), or
- a non-static data member of reference type, or
- a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because
  overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity
  or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or
- a direct or virtual base class B that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as
  applied to B’s corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted
  or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or
- for the move assignment operator, a non-static data member or direct base class with a type that does
  not have a move assignment operator and is not trivially copyable, or any direct or indirect virtual
  base class.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that you know the standard :) Do you have a sec. number?

Comment: The implicitly declared copy-assignment operator will also be defined as deleted if there is an explicitly declared move constructor or move assignment operator.

Comment: @Brian, thank, that I knew, was just curios about the assignment operator. It seems a bit odd that one cannot specify "explicit" for overloaded operators. It may be useful, especially when you deal with proxy objects.

Comment: @Barry, thanks, great answer, +1. Just edited "there are only 3 cases...." as they are actually 4 (last mentioned by @Brian), and you display them in bullets :)

Comment: @Barry, actually now I am a bit puzzled, so 12.8.18 seems to be saying that one assignment (copy) operator is declared if you don't declare one explicitly: `If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly`. But somehow it doesn't say that even if you declare one, there is still an implicit `Foo& operator=(const Foo&)`...

Comment: @vsoftco Ha, numbers! Thanks. I don't understand your last comment though.

Comment: @Barry, I'm just saying that the sentence: "If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly" is not equivalent to "A copy assignment operator is always declared, even if you explicitly specify one". Don't you agree?

Comment: @vsoftco Right, they're not equivalent. Why would you want the 2nd one?

Comment: @Barry, because, if you explicitly declare an `operator=`, I would expect the compiler to cool down and not declare an implicit one, so when I try (in my code) `a = b`, then it should not compile, as the user-defined `operator=` doesn't take a `Foo` as a parameter. Maybe I just misunderstood something.

Comment: Ahhh. I see the misunderstanding. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updated with an extra definition.

Comment: @Barry, great, got it, damn it, these things are really really tricky, and I find it absolutely impossible to remember all these nuances. I feel somehow that C++ became a bit of a monster with all these exceptions/interpretations etc, still it is my favourite language, but I really hope a dramatic simplification in the future. Thanks for the effort! PS: frankly, I had no idea that "copy operator" is not the same as "assignment operator" :)